# Title field only available

Tags: entries, matrix, field

I am currently working through the demo site Happy Lager and installed another separate instance of Craft from github as provided from the Craft site.

I am creating ‘modules’ and adding fields etc..

But

When I try to add an entry all I get is the title field. Even on the dashboard there is no option of including fields for population. Could you advise what seems to be the problem, the demo works fine and i’m especially interested in using the matrix functionality of the field functionality.

But all I get is the title field when I try to add an entry and have experimented with matrix and stand alone fields

Answer (score 2):

From reading your question it seems like the fields haven't been added to your entry type for the section you are trying to add entries to.

The first thing I'd recommend doing is to go to **Settings** > **Sections** then find the section in the list you are trying to add entries to. 
You should see an **Entry Types** column at the right; click on the **Edit entry type** option for the section.

This part of Craft allows you to add the fields you would like available in your entry. You can create your own tabs to categorise your fields as you see fit.

All you will need to do is drag the fields from the bottom of the screen into your field layout.

Go back to the entry and hopefully the fields you added will be showing!

Comment: Glad to help Mark!